# Show steps to convert $C^3-3CS^2$ to $4C^3-3C$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

In Visual Complex Analysis by Needham, on page 16, he converts $C^3-3CS^2$ to $4C^3-3C$  where C and S represent $\cos(\theta)$  and $\sin(\theta)$ respectively. He does this using $C^2+S^2=1$.  I have not been able to find the steps to go between these, even though it is trivial to plug in numbers and show that they are the same. Can you show me the algebra to equate these trig forms ?

I have tried factoring $C^2 + S^2$ out of $C^3-3CS^2$ but I just get $C$ remainder $-4CS^2$, which is to say that $C^2+S^2$  is not directly a factor.  I can see that somehow an extra $3C^3$ got added, maybe by some convenient form of multiplication by 1/1, but I don't see it.

Comment: $$C^3 - 3C(\underbrace{1-C^2}_{S^2}) = 4C^3-3C$$

Comment: I don't understand what it has to do with complex numbers, besides the books name

Comment: You will be seeing a lot of $\cos \theta$, $\sin\theta$.  Likely the author is just trying to help users warm up/review/master some trigonometry before venturing into complex analysis.  So think of exercises like this as a chance to review/master a bit of trig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall:  $\sin^2(x) = 1 - \cos^2(x)$

So,  $C^3 - 3CS^2 = C^3 - 3C(1 - C^2) = C^3 - 3C + 3C^3 = 4C^3 - 3C$

Answer (score 2):

$$C^3-3CS^2 = C^3 - 3C(1-C^2) = C^3 - 3C + 3C^3 = 4C^3-3C$$